# Is there a shortcut to setting Radio Buttons' Selected val when restoring via SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-preferences

If I have a number of RadioButtons, and I want to restore their state in the onResume() event, do I need to set each of the RadioButtons individually, a la:

```
KITPrefs = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
. . .
radioActive.setSelected(KITPrefs.getBoolean("radioActive", false));
radioFlyer.setSelected(KITPrefs.getBoolean("radioFlyer", false));
radioFreeEurope.setSelected(KITPrefs.getBoolean("radioFreeEurope", false));
```

...or is there a shortcut, where I can set the one value that is selected via a property of the RadioGroup or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be checking the single RadioButton, then you should be calling `setChecked(boolean)` rather than `setSelected(boolean)`. As long as all the RadioButtons are in a RadioGroup and they all have IDs, then selecting one will unselect any other that is set.

You can also call RadioGroup.check(id), but then you have to store the id of the checked item. This can work if you set the id to some constant value, but could cause problems if you use the generated ID values in R.java (the value could change).

Comment: These are two radio buttons in a RadioGroup, so I'm using setSelected() and putBoolean(...isSelected)